# Contents of executable files cannot be copied?

Tags: character-encoding, exe, executable, copy-paste

So, text files can be copied and pasted to another location by copying the contents of the original file into a blank text file. This can be done with a text editor. Highlight contents of text file, copy, create new blank text file, paste in to it.

But, why can't image, audio, video, executable files, etc., be copied and pasted like this? For example, I open an executable file with a text editor, copy all of it's contents, create a new blank text file, change the extension to .exe, and paste into it (through a text editor). But, the file cannot be run. Why?

Also, I would like to be able to edit these types of files like I do with text files. Is there a way?

Comment: Because the text editor you're using is only showing you printable characters, or replacing unprintable characters with spaces, rectangles, or other gibberish. When you copy this, you're copying a broken representation of the file. You need to open binary files (that's what they're called) in something like a hex editor. (Then also paste in a hex editor.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Wow! Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because executable and media files are "binary" files. Text files are binary as well, but different. All files are created binary, but some are created more binary than others.

You're opening a binary file in a text editor. This immediately changes the semantics of the bytes. The main problem is bytes containing a value that happens to correspond to those of newline characters if it were a text file (`0x0A` and `0x0D`), which will be rendered as a platform-dependent newline (`\r\n` on Windows, for example). When you copy that, you've changed either `0x0A` or `0x0D` to `0x0D 0x0A`.

Then there's control characters or non-printable characters. Not all bytes between `0x00` and `0xFF` can be represented as a character. They'll either be omitted or replaced with a displayable character.

So when you copy a text containing those, they'll be omitted or otherwise mangled.

In conclusion: you cannot reliably use text to display all possible byte values, unless you choose to encode the bytes' values, as is done using for example Base64 encoding.

If you want to edit a binary file, use an editor that is aware of those bytes: a "hex editor". Do note that changing random byte values in a binary file does not guarantee the sanity of that file: there may be checksums built into the format, and your edit will invalidate that checksum.

Comment: So a hex editor is what I need! Thanks a lot. Just another question. Why aren't the contents of the executable files 0s and 1s? Isn't that what the CPU understands?

Comment: The content of _every_ file is comprised of ones and zeroes. It's just a matter of representation. Would you rather read `0b01000001`, `0x41`, `65` or `A`?